Is Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT solvable in polynomial time?
I'm studying different variants of the SAT problem, and I came across the Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT problem.
Specifically, this problem involves determining whether a Boolean formula in CNF, where each clause contains exactly three positive literals (no negations), can be satisfied such that exactly 0, 2 or 3 out of the 3 literals in each clause are true.
From my understanding, many SAT variants like 3-SAT are NP-complete, but I have some notes that suggest this particular variant can be reduced to a problem involving dual Horn clauses, which is solvable in polynomial time. However, I'm not entirely clear on how this reduction works or whether it indeed implies that Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT is solvable in polynomial time.
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hajiagha/ALB14/09-23-2014.pdf
Page 3

My questions are:
Is Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT indeed solvable in polynomial time?
If so, could you explain how the reduction to a dual Horn problem works, or provide a reference that details this process?
Any insights or clarifications would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I've edited my question because Exactly-1-in-3SAT is something different than Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3 SAT.
Thanks to D.W. in the comments.

The PDF you link seems to talk about Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT (in every clause, 0, 2, or 3 variables are true), which is different from saying "exactly 2 out of the 3 literals in each clause are true".  Which do you mean?  If you mean the former, the lecture notes explain how to obtain Dual Horn clauses, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Sorry, it was a mistake. I've edited my question. I don't really understand how to obtain the dual Horn clauses... Wikipedia page yells that it's NP. So, I'm not sure.

It's called Not-Exactly-1 3SAT in the lecture notes, not Not-Exactly-1-in-3SAT.  Exactly-1-in-3 3SAT is something diffferent.

I've edited the question. Thank you very much . I was confused between Not-Exactly-1-in-3SAT and Not-Exactly-1 3SAT. I've written a small "proof".

Monotone Not-Exactly-1 3SAT problem (MNE1 3-SAT)
This problem involves determining whether a Boolean formula in CNF, where each clause contains exactly three positive literals (no negations), can be satisfied such that exactly 0, 2 or 3 out of the 3 literals in each clause are true.
From the definition, this truth table represents the function MNE1(A,B,C):



A
B
C
SAT




0
0
0
SAT


0
0
1



0
1
0



0
1
1
SAT


1
0
0



1
0
1
SAT


1
1
0
SAT


1
1
1
SAT



There are 3 exclusions:
$$(ABC \neq 001) (ABC \neq 010) (ABC \neq 100) $$
$$ = (A+B+\overline{C}) (A+\overline{B}+C) (\overline{A}+B+C) $$
$$ = (\overline{A} + B + C) ( A + \overline{B} + C) ( + A + B + \overline{C})$$
Following from the notes:
For each shift (i,j,k):
$$x_i \implies x_j + x_k$$
Hypothese: MNE1(A,B,C) is equal to:
$$ (A \implies B + C) (B \implies A + C) (C \implies A + B)  $$
We know that:
$$ p \implies q \equiv \overline{p} + q $$
We convert each clause with this equivalence:
$$(A \implies B + C) (B \implies A + C) (C \implies A + B)$$
$$= (\overline{A} + B + C) (\overline{B} + A + C) (\overline{C} + A + B) $$
$$ = (\overline{A} + B + C) ( A + \overline{B} + C) ( + A + B + \overline{C}) $$
We observe that the clauses are the same.
Conclusion
$$ MNE1(A,B,C) = (A \implies B + C) (B \implies A + C) (C \implies A + B) $$
This particular variant can be reduced to a problem involving only dual Horn clauses, which is solvable in polynomial time.
Thanks to D.W.

I'd say the 3 exclusions part (with the 3 clause derivation) already proves that this formula is a dual-Horn formula (when presented as a regular boolean formula).
